# How to run multiple spiders and their items class with pipelines in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to use single scrapy project for multiple scraping i.e multiple spiders here is my folder structure.

where scraper 1 runs with command like `scrapy crawl scar

```
project   
│
└───Spider
│   │---scraper1.py
│   │---scraper2.py
│---items.py
|---pipelines.py
|---settings.py
```

```
#scarper1.py


 class FloorSheetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "nepse"
        allowed_domains = ['nl.indeed.com']
    
        # start_urls = ['https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=AKPL']
    
        def start_requests(self):
            pass
        def parse(self, response):
            # other usecases
            items = NepalLiveShareItem() # this is items 1
            yeild items
```

This work fine for single spider but when I add another item class in scraper 2.py my items class for scraper1.py runs in pipeline any reason for this weird thing.
ps I have used separte pipeline for separate spider and registerd in settings too.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelines that are specified in the settings.py file runs for every spider that exists in the project.

If you want to run pipeline for a specific spider only, you need to specify it in the spider file.

For example:

```
class FloorSheetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nepse"
    allowed_domains = ['nl.indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=AKPL']
    
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'your_project.your_pipeline': 400
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # other usecases
        items = NepalLiveShareItem() # this is items 1
        yeild items
```